# How does typescript calculate type expr `interface extends index signature`?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

An example:

```
interface IndexSignature { [K: string]: unknown }
interface I { a: 1 }
type T = { a: 1 }

// I extends IndexSignature: no
const testI = (i: I): IndexSignature => i
// T extends IndexSignature: ok
const testT = (t: T): IndexSignature => t
```

I'm confused by this behaviour, how exactly does typescript calculate it internally? What exactly is the difference between an interface and a type alias in terms of meaning?

I know that interfaces can be redefined repeatedly, but in the above example the interface `I` is within the constraints of `[K:string]: unknown` no matter how many times it is redefined, right?

###### updated:

I know what design has said in [microsoft/TypeScript#15300](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300#issuecomment-332366024). The reason he mentions that interfaces cannot not operate this way is that - interfaces can be augmented - but in my case the index signature within `IndexSignature` is `[K: string]: unknown`, regardless of how the interface `I` is augmented. Its property value is a subclass of `unknown`. I think this is safe enough.

Comment: You've run into [ms/TS#15300](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300); one of the few differences between interfaces and anonymous object types is that the former are not given implicit index signatures.  See the answer to the linked question above for more information.